# Is there a way to know if a WPF application is shutting down?

Tags: wpf

I am writing some code that checks that my resources are properly cleaned up.

When the application is shutdown, resources are not cleaned up, which is fine. However, this makes my check code fail.

Is there a way to know if a WPF application is in the process of shutting down? - Something like Application.Current.IsShuttingDown?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [`Application.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx) event, you should be able to do with that.

If you really  need it to be a property, then create a property into your App class (your class inheriting `Windows.Application`) and set it to true in with the `Application.Exit` event.

Comment: Good idea . However the Application.Exit event is fired too late.

Comment: Works perfect! Just tat i Hated to create a static property! wonder why it wasnt made as part of Application Class.

Comment: Actually, it does indeed happen too late (**after** windows have been closed), at least for my scenario. I need this information inside the `Window.OnClosing` event. The reference source shows there would be plenty of indicators, but all of them are private or internal, so not usable.

Answer (score 7):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Hack to check if the application is shutting down.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsShuttingDown()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.Current.ShutdownMode = Application.Current.ShutdownMode;
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works very well.

Answer (score 3):

just add this to your App.cs file

```
    public bool IsShuttingDown { get; private set; }

    public new void Shutdown(int exitCode = 0)
    {
        this.IsShuttingDown = true;
        base.Shutdown(exitCode);
    }
```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55408561/edit) some explanation to your answer

Comment: this is an override of the Shutdown method provided by WPF itself, thus allowing you to do anything you want without interrupting the basic implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The IsShuttingDown property is an internal static property of the Application class therefore you can access to value it with the below code

```
var isShuttingDownProp = typeof(Application).GetProperty("IsShuttingDown", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic); 
var isShuttingDown = isShuttingDownProp.GetValue(Application.Current, null);
```