# Knowing whether shutdown was called when handling the closing event

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to ask the user if he really wants to close the application except in the situation when the application closes because of an unrecoverable error. 
By "unrecoverable error" I mean that while handling a caught exception `Application.Shutdown` is called.

Is there a way to know in the handler of the closing event of the main window if the event was triggered by the user closing the window or as a consequence of the call of `Application.Shutdown`?

As stated in the comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5070822/5525302) the `Application.Exit` event is triggered too late. The only way I can think of is to set a flag when calling `Application.Shutdown`. But this is error-prone since easy to forget.

Comment: check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdown?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @MichaelDaniloff: Thanks for the link, but what exactly are you refering to? I did not see the answer to my question on that page.